# How can I remove the ads by browser shop virus?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, malware

I've tried what everyone says to do, like removing the programs and resetting ALL my browsers and reinstalling chrome and firefox, and I've run scans with malwarebytes, adwcleaner, hitman, basically the works and nothing is removed. In chrome they appear EVERYWHERE and completely hide the search results. I've tried everything I can think of and need help on this one.

Comment: Reinstalling chrome and firefox only works if you also remove your entire settings (browser profile). By default that doesn't happen.

Comment: You've followed all the instructions here? http://malwaretips.com/blogs/browser-shop-removal/

Comment: which I did, I had it in each completely remove everything and then resynced my profile and even before then it was still there

Comment: and that was the exact webpage I followed

Comment: the problem with that one is I CAN"T REINSTALL AS I HAVE PROGRAMS ON HERE BUT NO KEYS

Comment: okay I've now went after it with malwarebytes chamelion, avast, and avg and nothing has been detected

Comment: @Excellll please remove that as that DOES NOT SOLVE MY PROBLEM, and it seems many conventional methods are not working

Comment: Hi. (1) Please don't shout at me. (2) There are are lots of useful answers on the linked Community Wiki page, not just the accepted answer. The two answers below that one I think are especially helpful. The link to Jeff Atwood's blog post about manually cleaning up an infestation with Process Explorer and Autoruns is also very instructive. (3) Marking as duplicate is a way of suggesting help not just to you but to others who come across this post. It's for reference, and it's there to help.

Comment: sorry, I read the first post and it said to wipe and reinstall and I just kind of ran away from that

Comment: ok I did a big rootkit scan with gdmr and removed something and after I rebooted chrome some extension showed up